# Scope of Page.Cache property in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

I'm now work on ASP.NET project
and want to use Page.Cache property to cache the String data like bellow way.
but, it behaves like having a Session scope.
I understand  Page.Cache property is retuning a current System.Caching.Cache object 
and that must have an Application scope.
I could check below code works fine, but my project's code not -- it makes cache for per session.
And, that replaced `Cache` of `Application` (with Lock and UnLock) works fine too.

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim key_str As String = "cache_key"
        Dim cached_value = Cache.Get(key_str)
        If cached_value Is Nothing Then
            cached_value = "stored_value"
            Cache.Insert(key_str, cached_value, Nothing, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), CacheItemPriority.Normal, New CacheItemRemovedCallback(AddressOf RemovedCallback))
        End If
        Label1.Text = cached_value
    End Sub
    Public Sub RemovedCallback(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As Object, ByVal removedReason As CacheItemRemovedReason)
        Debug.WriteLine("#Callback!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

- above code

  - works fine
- my project code

  - works like session scope
  - and If replaced `Cache` with `Application`, that works fine

Are there any possible to occur such a behavior or not?
(or I just made a mistake on anywhere else in logics?)

Please point out If concerning some configure files.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe made a mistake.
My project is a Azure project and so Page.Cache is to store a data for per azure instance? Right?